# Using a certain distribution function to compute certain integral.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have a random variable $\xi$ with function distribution (f.d.) $G$. Define the $p-$dimensional random vector as
$$X = (\psi_1 \xi , ..., \psi_p \xi) \sim F\,\,  ( F \hbox{ is f.d.})$$.

Given $a>0$, consider $A = [-a,a]^p$. I want to find an expression for:
$$ \int_ A d F$$
involving $G$ and the $\psi's$

My attempt is first try to find the f.d. of $X$:
\begin{align}
F(x_1,...,x_p) &= \mathbb{P}\left[ \psi_1 \xi \leq x_1, ..., \psi_p \xi \leq x_p\right]\\
&= \mathbb{P}\left[  \xi \leq \frac{x_1}{\psi_1}, ..., \xi \leq \frac{x_p}{\psi_p}\right]\\
&= \mathbb{P}\left[  \xi_n \leq \min \Big\{\frac{x_1}{\psi_1}, ...,\frac{x_p}{\psi_p}\Big\}\right]\\
&= G\Big(\min  \Big\{\frac{x_1}{\psi_1}, ...,\frac{x_p}{\psi_p}\Big\}\Big)
\end{align}

Even with these expressions in hand, I'm having serious trouble finding an expression for $\int_ A d F$.

Help!

Comment: Are $\psi_i$ constants or random variables?

Comment: They are constants!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your task is to determine
$\mathbb{P}(X \in A)$. First note that
$$\mathbb{P}(|\xi|\leq a) = \mathbb{P}(-a\leq \xi \leq a) =  G(a) - G(-a).$$
Hence, if $A = [-a,a]^d$, then we use arguments similar to what you wrote and the fact that $\psi_i$ are constant to get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X \in A) &= \mathbb{P}(|\psi_1\xi|\leq a,\ldots, |\psi_p\xi|\leq a)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\bigg(|\xi|\leq \frac{a}{\max(|\psi_1|,\ldots,|\psi_p|)}\bigg)\\
&= G\bigg(\frac{a}{\max(|\psi_1|,\ldots,|\psi_p|)}\bigg) - G\bigg(-\frac{a}{\max(|\psi_1|,\ldots,|\psi_p|)}\bigg).
\end{align*}